# Chromium taking a lot of memory

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, chromium

I am running a program on puppeteer with chromium, it starts with 69mb or memory used, but each second it goes up 7mb(!!) what can I do?

```
const scrape = async () => {
  //return Promise(async resolve => {
    var browser = await puppeteer.launch({
      headless:false,
      args: ['--disable-dev-shm-usage']
    });
    page = await browser.newPage();
    page.setViewport({ width: 1109, height: 969 });
    await page.goto("https://www.bustabit.com/game/"+valueToStart);
    for(var i = 1; i < 100000; i++){
      await page.waitForSelector(".modal-lg > .modal-content > .modal-body > .row > .col-sm-24 > h4");
      var dateAndTime = await page.$eval('.modal-body > .row > .col-sm-24 > h5:nth-child(5) > .bold',el=>el.textContent);
      var bustedAt = await page.$eval('.modal-body > .row > .col-sm-24 > h5:nth-child(4) > .bold',el=>el.textContent);
      var date = dateAndTime.substring(0,dateAndTime.length-13);
      var time = dateAndTime.substring(dateAndTime.length-13,dateAndTime.length);
      var game = new Game(i,date,time,bustedAt);
      allGames.push(game);
      var secsToWait = Math.floor(Math.random() * (1500 - 500 + 1)) + 500;
      //await sleep(secsToWait);
      if(i%100 == 0){
        var f =await createExcel(allGames);
        f.write(EXCEL_NAME);
      }
      console.log(allGames.length + " / " + 10000 + " " + EXCEL_NAME);
      await page.waitForSelector('.col-sm-24 > nav > .pager > .next > a')
      await page.click('.col-sm-24 > nav > .pager > .next > a');

    }
    var f =await createExcel(allGames);
    f.write(EXCEL_NAME);
    //resolve("done!");
  //});
}
```

Comment: This might be a question for https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @kai Not as currently phrased. It would need more information. For example, the purpose of the code provided and the required context in which the code runs.

Comment: Can you give your environment details (local or server, Node version, puppeteer version etc.)? Chromium memory handling is far from perfect when it comes to automation, maybe you will need extra launch flags to improve on the growing memory usage: https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/